# In-stock Product Count by Day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of active work days:

```
--------------
|    DATE    |
--------------
| 01/06/2014 |
| 01/07/2014 |
|    ...     |
--------------
```

And I have a huge list of products:

```
----------------------------------
| Name  |  Received  |   Sold    |
----------------------------------
| Jam   | 01/04/2014 |           |
| Honey | 01/04/2014 | 01/07/2014|
----------------------------------
```

I want to be able to count the number of products in stock that were received before or on each work day, but weren't sold on that same work day (Once a product has been sold on a date, no future date should count it).

So, results for the simple example above would look like:

```
------------------------
|    DATE    |  Count  |
------------------------
| 01/06/2014 |    2    | // 2 products received on 01/04/2014, none sold by 01/06
| 01/07/2014 |    1    | // 2 products received on 01/04, but 1 sold on 01/07
|    ...     |   ...   |
------------------------
```

I tried doing a loop over the `DATE` but I think that'd require me to insert into a table, which I'm trying to avoid.

I also don't think I can do a simple `GROUP BY`.

Is there a clean and elegant solution to this using a partition or something in Oracle? (I'm not terribly familiar with Oracle yet). This is also restricted to Oracle 10.g...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple join between work days and products table

```
select w.work_date, count(p.name) 
from workdays as w
join products as p
  on p.received < w.work_date and (p.sold is null or p.sold > w.work_date)
group by w.work_date
```

Comment: But will this query work if more dates are added to workdays and more items are added to products? `p.received < w.work_date` condition will keep on counting all the products that were received before particular work day.  for example, if i add one more item to products as `Butter, 01/03/2014, null`, count will change to 2 and 3 for 06-jan-14 and 04-jan-14 and that is not the requirement of OP.

Comment: the requirement is "to be able to count the number of products in stock that were received before each work day, but weren't sold on that same work day." the new item `butter, 01/03/2014, null` was received before either of the two workdays and was not sold on those dates. so the naturally the count should increase for both, right?

Comment: @z33m - that's correct.  Butter should also not be counted for any days after it was sold though.

Comment: i think changing the `<>` condition to `>` should produce your result.

Comment: I think `p.received < w.work_date` has to be a `<=` too.

Comment: yes. if you want to be able to count "stock that were received *on or* before each work day" too